# Scala Regex to get table name from query excluding some special character

Tags: regex, scala

I want to get table name from query, I have something like this:

```
 Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(?:exists|from|join)\\s?([a-zA-Z0-9_$#-]*\\.?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*)")
```

its work's but when I have query like

"select some1,some2 when some1=1 and some2 IN ('something something from somewhere') from tableName

Then I got value "somewhere", because I have more than once "from".
How can I write regex to skip parts in '( )'?

Comment: The main question is what to do with nested parentheses? Java/Scala regex does not support recursion. Write a simple parser, do not use regex.

Comment: But unfortunately, I need to have regex. I have something like this: """.*(from|FROM)\s*([^\s*][^\n\r]*)""".r  but it get everything after "from"

Comment: Add `(?![^()]*\))` at the end (if you are not using `"""` literal, double the backslash).

Comment: Works! Thank you Wiktor.

Comment: Note this is not a generic solution, it will work only for some subset of queries that have no nested parentheses.